# I'm needing to figure out how to create a page that user could create a "task" and it be selectable on a form

Tags: forms, calendar

Essentially what I am looking to do is to have a page designed that is only accessible through a client login, but the one page would have the ability to create a "calendar task" if you will. So they would be able to name it, put the text body and assign a start date and end date, and of course save it.

Then after it's saved they can go to the schedule tab which would have a day of each week and the available time slots, basically like a form, and each time slot would have a drop down that they would then be able to select which task they previously created and saved goes into that time slot.

For example:

Monday, 6am has 5 options, 6:05, 6:20, 6:35, and 6:35.  Each of those times would have a drop down available and the user has the option of selecting General, or from a list of one of the task that was created.

Then the same for the 7am, hour, and so on for all 24 hours.

I don't know if this can be accomplished in some form of calendar plugin, or a form, or what.  I'm looking for suggestions.

Comment: This is a tough question to answer because there's more than one way to achieve what you're looking for, so it's going to be difficult to accurately select a correct answer.  My suggestion would be to generate a plugin with a Custom Post Type, then determine what user-level your clients are going to be, then determine if they're accessing the WP admin or if you need to create a template to let them do this on the front end.  I've built similar stuff but not exactly like this, so it's very do-able.

Comment: Do I need to create a form to accomplish the actual placement of the task? The user login part isn’t throwing me as much as how to accomplish having one page that a user can write a task with a start date and expiration, basically like a calendar event and then have it as a selectable option on the page that has the days and time slots. That’s where I’m stuck.

Comment: If not a form than what else?  All inputs are basically forms whether they look like one or not, if the user is providing information then it's going to have to technically be a 'form' of some sort.  Or am I just not understanding what you're asking?